# Problema en MYSQL, ayuda por favor

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En base a este diagrama me solicitaron hacer estas consultas. Tengo poco conocimiento en este tema y necesito algún tipo de guía, estoy usando mysql, motor de base de datos distinto al que algunos años atras use que era oracle, pero recuerdo muy poco. Si podrían ayudarme para guiarme por favor.

Listar los autores que no tengan libros relacionados

Listar los autores con más de 2 libros

Listar por Tema la cantidad de libros, las paginas en total y precio promedio.

Listar que tema su precio promedio no exceda de 350

Listar que tema su total de páginas no supere 850

Listar autores que escribieron libros de ficción o salud

Listar el autor que escribió más libros

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas suelen ser cerradas. Te sugiero que revises [ask] para que mejores tu pregunta y sea mejor recibida. Que has intentado? Es mejor que lo intentes tu y si tienes errores en el intento consultes especificamente eso.

Comment: Pasa que mi conocimiento en estos temas es casi nulo, me lo han dejado como un plus, pero solo he podido hacer 2 que eran básicas, esas me resultan difíciles por eso pido ayuda, para que me pueda guiar de los que conocen más...

Comment: Pensé haberlo borrado, ahora lo hago...

Answer (score 1):

@ItamarSolis, sinceramente creo que estás pidiendo que te hagamos el trabajo, pero de todas formas te dejare unos tips que te pueden guiar para buscar la información que necesitas:

1- Listar los autores que no tengan libros relacionados.
Para resolver esta query podrías ocupar la clausula not exists o el valor null para el filtro en el campo id_autor

2- Listar los autores con más de 2 libros.
Para esta query podrías ocupar un having count () donde la cantidad de libros relacionados al autor sea mayor a 2.

3- Listar por Tema la cantidad de libros, las paginas en total y precio promedio.
Para esta query podrías hacer un count() de todos los libros agrupados por cada cosa que te piden.

4- Listar que tema su precio promedio no exceda de 350.
Para esto puedes ocupar el operador lógico > 350.

5- Listar que tema su total de páginas no supere 850.
Para esto puedes ocupar el operado lógico <= 850

Listar autores que escribieron libros de ficción o salud.
Para esto tendrías que hacer un join con los autores, libros y temas relacionados donde el tema este dentro de los temas mencionados con un IN por ejemplo.

Listar el autor que escribió más libros.
Para esto puedes hacer un count del autor que más libros tenga asociados.

Espero que estos tips te sean de ayuda, de todas maneras te recomiendo leer la documentación oficial de MySql o ver algún tutorial en youtube donde explican bastante bien como operar y entender las bases de datos.

No se que versión estaras ocupando pero aquí te dejo el link de la documentación oficial de MySql:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tutorial.html

Y aquí estan todos los documentos oficiales de Mysql y sus productos.

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Saludos